# Find all parts in Sheet1 that have value > 0 for days production

Tags: excel

I have a Gigantic excel workbook at the company i work for to schedule the daily production. I am attempting to make it easier for the fabrication dept to know exactly what parts they need each day.

Sheet1  dates (aug1 - oct 23) in row 1 starting in column b and a list of parts in column a from row 2 to row 3000.

In sheet 2 I would like the fab dept to enter the date in A1 and then a list be generated showing the parts and how many of that part match for the day entered, but to exclude parts that are empty.

I'm really lost. I am a programmer of many languages but never really do anything besides a basic IF or VLOOKUP in excel.

Comment: What version of Excel (2003,2007, 2010)?

Comment: You could probably get away with a fairly simple Advanced Filter (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx) and, maybe a macro (button) to actually run the filter... Just one idea of how this could be done...